# How decomposition is dependency preserving?

Tags: database, relational-database, normalization, database-normalization, functional-dependencies

Let R (A, B, C, D) be a relational schema with the following functional dependencies :
A → B, B → C,
C → D and D → B. The decomposition of R into (A, B), (B, C), (B, D)

> How decomposition  is dependency preserving?

---

Somewhere it explained as "The given decomposition is also dependency preserving as the dependencies A->B is present in (A, B), B->C is present in (B, C), D->B is present in (B, D) and C->D is indirectly present via C->B in (B, C) and B->D in (B, D)."

> But my question is, if B→C is given then C→B need not be, right?
>   Can you explain please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, `C → B` is determined by all the other dependencies `F = {A → B, B → C, C → D, D → B}`.

To show this, you have to see if the closure of `C` with respect to `F` contains `B`. Giving the results of the intermediate steps of the algorithm for the closure of a set of attributes:

```
C+ = C
C+ = CD (by using the third dependency)
C+ = CDB (by using the fourth dependency)
```

So, since `C+` contains `B`, then `C → B` can be derived from the other dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation.